# How to attempt to perform an action in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an automated script that clicks on a button, which triggers a bootstrap modal dialog box, with confirmation button. My javascript code looks like this:

```
const bookScript = () => {
    const confirm = () => {
        const el = document.querySelector('.confirm');
        if (el) {
            el.click();
            return;
        }
        setTimeout(() => confirm(), 10);
    };
    let bookBtn = document.evaluate("//button[text()='Foo'][1]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    if (bookBtn) {
        bookBtn.click();
        confirm();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

There might be a case when modal dialog does not show up, in that case, this script should return false, but I want it to wait for the modal to show up for at least 3 seconds, how can I code that?

Answer (score 1):

The same way you've done with your set timeout.

```
setTimeout( () => {
  let bookBtn = document.evaluate("//button[text()='Foo'][1]", document, null, 
  XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    if (bookBtn) {
        bookBtn.click();
        confirm();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}, 3000)
```

Comment: hmm, but, I have recursive `setTimeout(() => confirm(), 10);`, how can I break from that recursion in 3 seconds?